# How to get Page.UICulture in a static WebMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind, webmethod

How to get the `Page.UICulture` in a `static` `WebMethod` function. The following gives me an error:

```
Page.UICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

The error I get:

> An object reference is required for the non static field,method or property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, you can't.

The property `Page` is not available to a `static` method, and that makes sense, since in the context of that static `WebMethod`, you don't have a page.

You could save the relevant properties in a `Session` variable and get it from the session info in your `WebMethod`. Note you have to set `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]` to be able to get the session info from a `WebMethod`.

Comment: 2Will `Page.UICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;` cause compilation error or runtime exception?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: Usually when compiling. It is in the code, not in the markup. That would make it compile time checked.